# Firebase email verification goes to spam folder

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I made a mobile app and used Firebase for backend and authentication. When I use firebase's built in email verification, the email always goes to the junk folder / spam.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @JoshKarol, did you find the solution to this in the end?

Answer (score 9):

That's weird. Firebase made restrictions to avoid this problem. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075602/firebase-authentication-email-customisation/50077575#50077575)

Spam filters normally look for these things:

- **Subject Line:** looking for common words and phrases associated with spam.
- **Content**: looking for suspicious links, low text to image ratios, and other spammy hallmarks.
- **Metadata**: looking at the To/From/CC fields, the sender’s domain, and embedded code.
- **IP address:** looking for IPs that have been flagged frequently as spam by both filters and recipients in the past.

[More Info](https://ninjaforms.com/why-your-email-gets-sent-to-spam-quick-tips-to-keep-out-of-the-can/)

---

Ill suggest using your own domain to send emails. You can check [this article](https://medium.com/@arutkayb/firebase-auth-how-to-set-up-a-custom-domain-for-email-templates-1693999224be) on how to do this. You will also get the extra benefit of looking more professional.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the headers of the received email message. Typically, Antispam tools use headers to add the detail of the scoring elements that lead to the message being flagged as spam. This will give you insights on why this happens since reasons can be multiple and cumulative (Title, content, DNS, DKIM, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by only changing the project name.

Go to your firebase project > Project Settings > Main page.

There you'll see some public settings, change the name of your project, the default will show something like "project-(yourProjectId)", put for example "Project Name".

Comment: Also did not fix for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem,
The problem is that your sender name is `noreply@project.firebaseapp.com`
and that made all my emails going to spam.

What I did was to visit my console
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project_name/authentication/emails

which is the template tab of the Authentication page.

Click on the pencil icon and click on the `Customize Domain`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xayxk.png)

Add and verify your domain.

That will solve the problem

Comment: Did not solve for me.