# Change the email template when using Firebase email link authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase supports password-less email logins. A user provides their email, and then Firebase emails them a login link.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth

However, I don't see any way to change the email text. This is the default:

```
Sign in to project-XXXX

Hello,

We received a request to sign in to project-XXXX using this email address. If you want to sign in with your XXXX@XXXX.com account, click this link:

Sign in to project-XXXX

If you did not request this link, you can safely ignore this email.

Thanks,

Your project-XXXX team
```

The Authentication > Templates section of Firebase Console only shows the following options. None of them match the text above:

[image: templates]

Comment: When you hover over question mark it says : "To help prevent spam, the message can't be edited on this email template"  But if you want this changes you can do feature request : https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: That is not what my UI says when I hover the question mark. Mine says `Email templates are only sent to Email/Password users`.

Comment: this is the only way I found to do so https://stackoverflow.com/a/63472996/2311662

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot, Firebase prevent this in order to avoid being used for spam. If you want to change the email, you need to handle the flow by yourself.

#### More info/references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077575/5869296

Comment: Can we at least change the project-XXXX reference?

Comment: @Binajmen Yes, change "Public-facing name" in the general project settings.

Answer (score 0):

The way Firebase has the message content locked down makes sense to me (I am currently using the Firebase email/password authentication) -or I should say, makes sense for at least specifically for the password reset message.

For the email confirmation message, as @Kayce pointed out, user has to be logged in.  I can only imagine that there was some security/spam concern that Firebase folks thought of that I cannot come up with.

If customization was allowed for password reset messages, anyone with an email list that they want to spam can write a simple app,  customize the message to whatever they want and have Firebase send that message to any email address that they want to spam (but I understand the question was about email verification emails).

Strangely, they do allow edits of the password reset emails.

Comment: The email template that I'm referring to is only sent when you log in to an app. So it's not possible for developers to spam whenever they want.

Comment: True enough, Kayce (I have updated my comment above).  Valid for the password reset email, though.