# Firebase authentication custom password reset template with HTML/CSS

Tags: firebase, email, firebase-authentication

I have a question regarding Firebase Authentication custom email template for Password Reset.

If I simply add a `space` in the message, the email received is in plain text instead of html formatted.
Anyone know whether custom email template support html / css ? or something I have missed ?

The default email with

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

The customized email with

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Updated:

> Short answer is NO, you cannot do it.

**Below is the explanation from Firebase Support:**

> Currently it is not possible to change the Firebase email template. We understand that changing the template would allow you to tweak the user-experience of your app, but we don't allow this to prevent abuse of the service. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

> One possible workaround is to send custom emails by using the Admin SDK to generate and send your own emails containing confirmation links. In this way you can configure the content of the email, here is a link [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334804/change-the-email-template-when-using-firebase-email-link-authentication) with an entry in Stackoverflow with more information.

Comment: did you manage to fix this, we are experiencing the same issue ?

Comment: Same issue, hope figure out why