# Need to customize firebase email template which can be used in angular

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a service to send sendemailtologin but now, I need to use my own email template with all details. I have gone through the documents, nothing helped me. Kindy come forward and explain, if anyone already did.
The templates will be stored in firestore, if user click for passworldess login, a custome email template should be send with details.

Comment: Is https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler what you are looking for?

Comment: I will be having custom templates in firebase storage. For example, passworldess login I need to use that corresponding template from storage to send the email to the user to login.

Comment: "having custom templates in firebase storage": It seems feasible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am stuck https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler in this document, not able to find a solution to get the template from firebase storage and send that template as a email to user for login.

Comment: There is only a limited amount you can customize about the Firebase Authentication email template, as otherwise it'd be open to abuse for spam. If you want to send emails that are substantially different from the one Firebase has, you will have to build your own email sending service, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075602/firebase-authentication-email-customisation

Comment: Great thanks, let me see..

Comment: I got it ... Thanks to all...