# Firebase customize email verification template

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm new in firebase and flutter.
At the moment i try to edit my firebase email template.
I would like add some pictures and custom code to have a better ui.
I have looking in internet for some help.

This is waht i found:

- [Firebase authentication email customisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075602/firebase-authentication-email-customisation)
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

But i'm not sure waht i have to do?

My questions:

- Where i implement 'custom email action handler'?
- Do i need the firebase admin skd?
- Do i need a smpt server to send email?
- Where i implement the email template (in flutter app or on firebase)?

Can anyone help me with my problem?
I would be very happy if you can give me a full example.
If you have any questions feel free to ask me.

Many thx (:

Answer (score 0):

1> for custom email action handler you would have to create your own handlers (using HTML and  js , react app , flutter anything you want) after doing that you can either test your handler by routing traffic to it (localhost) using ngrok(that will provide you with https url to route traffic on localhost, preferred method for testing)  , or you can deploy it and directly use that url . now with that url go to firebase(your project) -> authentication -> templates -> use whatever handler you want( example reset password or email verification) -> edit and add custom action url to route traffic to your handler( hosted(deployed) or local(ngrok routing) .

2> use can use Firebase SDK or import CDNS (easier way).
example instead firebase/app use CDNS.
I think other two questions are answered above only .

(https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler/)!