# How to distinguish email-verified user from non-verified user on Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase and found could not distinguish email-verified user from non-verified user on user list in console.

I know that we can distinguish those users with code-basis like followings but how can I confirm it on console in Firebase Authentication ?

```
      UserCredential _result =
                        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: _email,
                      password: _pswd,
                    );

                    _result.user!.sendEmailVerification();
```

By the way, I believe we cannot change `DISPLAY NAME` in email template for authentication, is this right or actually we can insert certain value instead ?
Please refer the part circled red in Screen Shot below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How can I confirm it on console in Firebase Authentication

There is no way in the console to identify email-verified users from non-verified users

> I believe we cannot change DISPLAY NAME in email template for
> authentication, is this right or actually we can insert certain value
> instead ?

No you cannot modify the template for email verification. More details in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077575/3371862). But you can build your own email format/template as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) in the doc.

Comment: Thanks for helpful comment. As for latter question,  it also indicates template in the console as following:

Comment: <p>Hello %DISPLAY_NAME%,</p> <!--here-->
<p>Follow this link to verify your email address.</p>
<p><a href='%LINK%'>%LINK%</a></p>
<p>If you didn’t ask to verify this address, you can ignore this email.</p>
<p>Thanks,</p>
<p>Your %APP_NAME% team</p>

Comment: Could you add, in your question, a screenshot of the template you are mentioning. Just to be sure I fully understand your question/problem.

Comment: Thanks again and added screenshot  as above!

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Thanks for updates, but could not find building own format/ template in doc shown, I'll check more in details

Comment: You are in charge of sending the email with the way you want. Hence you are on full control of the template design. Personally I use Sengrid

Comment: I have never heard about Sendgrid or such kind of service. And I searched like "sendgrid firebase" and found lot of related articles and figured out it possibly could solve my problem above !

Comment: Use Sendgrid to send the emails and follow the doc referred to on my answer for the email verification