# How to configure Firebase Magic Link Authentication email App Name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

When I receive an email from magic link authentication, it has the `Sign in to project-xxxx` subject and also `project-xxxx` all over in the body.

How do I change `project-xxxx` to public name of my app?

I can see in comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075602/firebase-authentication-email-customisation) I should set

> "Public-facing name" in project settings

However, I don't seem to be able to find such a field (anymore?).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cha I figured it out, so it turns out that to enable Public Settings Google Sign-in method needs to be enabled as well (even if you are not planning to use it)!

After Google sign in is enabled, setting Public Facing Name does the trick.

[image: Public Settings]