Email verification code generation on api endpoint using nuxt and inserting it to firebase
I have created file called emailVerification.js in server/api folder
const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

function generateVerificationCode(length) {
    let result = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        result += chars[randomIndex];
    }
    return result;
}

export async function generateEmailVerificationCode() {
    try {
        const verificationCode = generateVerificationCode(32);
        return {
            verificationCode
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error generating verification code:', error);
        throw new Error('Failed to generate verification code');
    }
}

and in firebase.js that is located in composables
    const { verificationCode } = await generateEmailVerificationCode();

    await addDoc(collection(db, "email_verification"), {
        account_id: user.uid,
        verification_code: verificationCode,
        created_at: serverTimestamp()
    });

Is this generally good practise to generate verification code on api endpoint? Can it be potentially exposed on the client? Is my implementation correct?

I am not sure where are those files, but it's probably a bad idea to do something homemade and naive as you did here. Prefer using a package to handle it with a better algorithm with no collisions etc. Also, what is the question exactly? You can do it whenever pleases you otherwise, better on the backend indeed.

Just wanted to know if that generated code from api point can be visible on the client side upon code generation. Because I want that generated code to be inserted in firebase so user could enter the code from email that I will send.

It is not really visible on the client-side no, stay on Nuxt's server part. I still remember to send it directly to Firebase or some other cloud functions to handle that part on the backend and not mix things inside of your Nuxt app. What even is this verification code? Oh and make sure to not call the composable in an isomorphic place (server + client). Overall, I'd recommend for you to handle that part entirely on Firebase if possible.

It's email verification code. It's impossible to customize email confirmation template from firebase as far as i know so I will combine nodemailer with nuxt that will send the code (with my own custom email verification template). Upon visiting the link with the code account will activate.

Could you comment on this part - not call the composable in an isomorphic place (server + client)

You're saying that Firebase cannot very an email for you? High doubts on this one. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_a_web_page As for the isomorphic part, make sure that the composable does not run on client-side.

I'm aware it can verify email addresses but I'm saying the email verification template cannot be customized. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077575/22423195

Gonna probably need a custom template then indeed.
